# Using Q solution with ready made MasterMix

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, pcr

I am exploring the possibility of using Q solution (5x) to get rid of non specific bands in PCR. I mostly use a MasterMix and not separate aliquots of dNTPs, Taq, buffer etc. In principle, adding Q solution to the reaction mixture when I use MM should be fine, but I just wanted to ask if someone has done so and had success (or failure?) before.